# ant d table, add comma to data values of array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, angular, antd

so in my ant d table I am getting data vals
array - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

in my table the data appears as 12345

I want to add comma and space in the middle

suppose for example take this code, I want comma between the tags

https://codesandbox.io/s/62ft4

> import React from 'react'; import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; import
> 'antd/dist/antd.css'; import './index.css'; import { Table, Tag, Space
> } from 'antd';
>
> const columns = [   {
> title: 'Name',
> dataIndex: 'name',
> key: 'name',
> render: text => {text},   },   {
> title: 'Age',
> dataIndex: 'age',
> key: 'age',   },   {
> title: 'Address',
> dataIndex: 'address',
> key: 'address',   },   {
> title: 'Tags',
> key: 'tags',
> dataIndex: 'tags',
> render: tags => (
> <>
> {tags.map(tag => {
> let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
> if (tag === 'loser') {
> color = 'volcano';
> }
> return (
>
> {tag.toUpperCase()}
>
> );
> })}
> </>
> ),   },   {
> title: 'Action',
> key: 'action',
> render: (text, record) => (
>
> Invite {record.name}
> Delete
>
> ),   }, ];
>
> const data = [   {
> key: '1',
> name: 'John Brown',
> age: 32,
> address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
> tags: ['nice', 'developer'],   },   {
> key: '2',
> name: 'Jim Green',
> age: 42,
> address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
> tags: ['loser'],   },   {
> key: '3',
> name: 'Joe Black',
> age: 32,
> address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
> tags: ['cool', 'teacher'],   }, ];
>
> ReactDOM.render(,
> document.getElementById('container'));

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this website is used as Q-A and all posts should work as helpful posts for future readers. Thus all the code is requested to be contained within the question itself and not on an external link, that can die out by time. Please edit the question and append your code there with proper editing.

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-17-1-alpha-0-forked-s7iv6?file=/index.js

this is what worked
using the reduce function

```
 {tags
          .map((tag) => {
            return <Tag key={tag}>{tag}</Tag>;
          })
          .reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ", ", curr])}
```